# onclick execute  doesn't work

Tags: ajax, onclick

this piece of code is not working somehow, do you see any flaws?

```
    $('#button').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'action.php'
      }
   });
});
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Use firebug console to see if the event is actually firing, and you see a POST request to the host/action.php when you click on the button.

Comment: do you have the html? is jquery lib loaded? is your script in the document ready function?

Comment: when I click on the button with id 'button', nothing happens, the action.php file is not being executed

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?  Because you have too many `}`s.  You should see a syntax error in your console.

Comment: removing the } fixed it, thanks guys :) sorry for the 'noobishness'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $.post("test.php");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an unmatched }

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'action.php'
      // } <--- Not necessary
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'action.php'
   });
});
```

Notice that you had an extra `}`